# Java massive memory consumption/leak when creating new objects in a while loop

Tags: java, memory-leaks, while-loop

I have the following program that runs on a txt file of size 2GB with 80M lines.
Each line of the txt file has the following format:

word1_POSTAG word2_POSTAG frequency

for example:

academy_NN award_NN 200

The while loop by which I read the file line by line and extract and store the information from each line, uses up all my 16GB of memory very quickly (at around line 35M).
I do not seem to find the problem. I tried to force garbage collection, and make `elements` and `tmp` null after their usage at each iteration, but none of these works.

```
     BufferedReader tagged = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream(p2_POSTagged_bigrams), "UTF8"));

     HashMap<String,TaggedNgram_v2> taggedEtFreq = new HashMap();


     int linecount = 0;
     String s1 = "";
     while((s1=tagged.readLine()) != null){
         linecount++;

         if(linecount % 1000000 == 0){
             System.out.println("processing line: "+linecount);
         }

         String[] elements =s1.split("[ _]");//s1 format: academy_NN award_NN 254           

        if(!taggedEtFreq.containsKey(elements[0].concat(" ").concat(elements[2])) ){

             TaggedNgram_v2 tmp = new TaggedNgram_v2();
             tmp.addTags(elements[1].concat(" ").concat(elements[3]));
             tmp.addTagFrequency(Integer.parseInt(elements[4]));
             taggedEtFreq.put(elements[0].concat(" ").concat(elements[2]), tmp);

         }else{

             TaggedNgram_v2 tmp = taggedEtFreq.get(elements[0].concat(" ").concat(elements[2]));
             tmp.addTags(elements[1].concat(" ").concat(elements[3]));
             tmp.addTagFrequency(Integer.parseInt(elements[4]));
             taggedEtFreq.put(elements[0].concat(" ").concat(elements[2]), tmp);

         }  
     }
```

and I define `TaggedNgram_v2` class as follows.

```
class TaggedNgram_v2 {

private List<String> tags = new ArrayList();
private List<Integer> tagFrequencies = new ArrayList();

public List<String> getTags() {
    return tags;
}

public void addTags(String tag) {
    tags.add(tag);
}

public List<Integer> getTagFrequency() {
    return tagFrequencies;
}

public void addTagFrequency(int tagFrequency) {
    tagFrequencies.add(tagFrequency);
}

}
```

Comment: Why do you want them in the memory? That has database written all over it.

Comment: It's curious why it takes so much memory, as long as the file has only 2 Gb and you only read less than a half of it. But definetly, in this case, the garbage collector can't do much, as all the objects remain referenced in the hash. You can try to debug by only reading the file into an array list, and see if it still takes so much memory, or just compare with the actual one.

Comment: To my surprise, when inside the while loop, I solely add the lines to an `ArrayList` it still consumes about 9GB of memory.